# Screen Tearing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, screen, tearing

So I have recently switched to Ubuntu 18.04. LTS and I'm getting a lot of screen tearing especially during video playback on e.g. YouTube. Could anybody help me fix this? Note that I'm completely new to Linux.

Comment: What's your video card? Nvidia, AMD, or Intel?

Comment: Have you installed any video drivers? Open `Software & Updates`, `Additional Drivers` tab, and tell me what you see.

Comment: I've never made it work when using Nvidia, however if you use intel video cards, you can follow this trick here: https://github.com/bauca/graphics-switcher

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For Firefox do this:

- Type "about:config" on the address bar.
- Search for `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` (default is `false`). This forces Hardware Acceleration to turn on.
- Change it to `true` by double-clicking.
- Save and restart Firefox.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: What is this actually doing?

Answer (score 7):

There is a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvD9JvEna8o) that fixed it for me. The short version for Ubuntu 19, is that I had to open "Startup Applications" and add a new item with the command:

```bsh
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

Comment: This helped on Kde Plasma with tearing when dragging windows and also on chrome when scrolling and watching videos.

Comment: If you have a dual monitor setup, you'll need something like:
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +1680+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }, DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"

Comment: I believe you can fix this permanently (without setting a startup app). Open NVIDIA X Server Settings app -> X Server Display Configuration -> click 'Advanced' and then set the "Force Composition Pipeline" and "Force Full Composition Pipeline" checkboxes.  Apply. To make permanent click Save X Configuration File.  (NB for that to work I had to `sudo chmod u+x /usr/share/screen-resolution-extra/nvidia-polkit`)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you have hardware acceleration enabled in your browser and supported by your GPU driver.

**Google Chrome / Chromium**

1. Go to *Settings* → *Advanced* → *System*.
2. Check *Use hardware acceleration when available*.

For debug open this URL (paste it into your address bar):

```
chrome://gpu/
```

**Firefox**

1. Go to *Preferences* → *Performance*.
2. Un-check *Use recommended performance settings*.
3. Check *Use hardware acceleration when available*.

For debugging, open this URL (paste it into your address bar):

```
about:support
```

and look for *Graphics* info.

**Checking GPU drivers**

To check what driver is in use open terminal and run:

```
lspci -v | less
```

then press <kbd>/</kbd>, type `VGA` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

In the VGA section you'll see your video card model, available drivers and drivers in-use.

Example:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation [GeForce] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
(...)
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Depending on your graphics card you may want to switch between open source and proprietary driver.

Open source drivers are better for 2D rendering, but have lower performance for 3D acceleration.

**Switching drivers**

Go to *System settings* → *Updates* → *Settings* → *Additional drivers*.

You should be able to also open this tab via terminal with:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab 2
```

Then you can switch between drivers, then reboot your PC.

**Intel graphics**

For Intel integrated graphics go to: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/

**NVIDIA screen tearing**

You may find these answers useful:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/992333/950482
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1110975/950482

Comment: For chrome I needed to also enable flag chrome://flags/#enable-accelerated-video-decode

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Intel driver (check with `lspci` command) simply create a file:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

with content:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Intel Graphics"
  Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

Then reboot.

This helped me to remove screen tearing and flickering.

Comment: I think, we need to run "sudo update-initramfs -u" command after writing that content as suggested. Unless I am wrong but AM I WRONG?

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem and I fixed it just simply by changing the refresh rate in the display settings. Instead of using 60Hz I used 59.96Hz

[image: Display Settings screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

I get fixed by turning off hardware acceleration in browser setting. I experienced youtube tearing every time with every version of anything. My system was Intel i3-4th gen with intel HD graphics.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how to turn off hardware acceleration?  Is it specific to a certain browser?