# Screen tearing on youtube videos UBUNTU 20.4

Tags: intel-graphics

I got some screen tearing when i'm watching videos on internet,
My graphic card is an integrated Intel HD 4000 on an intel i7 3770
I also got 4 GB RAM and 500 GB HDD
¿Any soluition?
I already tried with 20-intel.config :( Help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen Tearing Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141291/screen-tearing-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with firefox and I solved it by changing `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` to `true`. here is how:

type `about:config` in the address bar, hit enter, click on **Accept the Risk and Continue**, find `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` and change it's value to `true` then restart firefox.

You can test if you're still having the tearing problem by watching this video on 1080p and 60fps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RvIbVmCOxg

Comment: I love you bro.

Answer (score 1):

For chrome, it is enabling hardware acceleration in settings and enabling flag `chrome://flags/#enable-accelerated-video-decode`

GPU acceleration status is listed here: `chrome://gpu/`

For me, after turning the flag enabled, the video decoding became hardware accelerated(previously was software  only)

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
OpenGL: Enabled
Hardware Protected Video Decode: Unavailable
Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Skia Renderer: Enabled
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated 
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
```