# How do I solve screen tearing on Ubuntu 18.04 with NVIDIA?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, tearing

The answer on [Nvidia drivers - Unable to check "Force full composition pipeline"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968443/) does something that makes my laptop unable to detect the external monitor. Undoing the solution restores the ability to detect the second monitor. I'm still left with tearing on any type of video playback. Youtube, video player, etc.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with i7-8750H and RTX 2070 (nvidia-driver-430).

**Edit:**

Output of `inxi`:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 3e9b
           Card-2: NVIDIA Device 1f10
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 )
           drivers: modesetting,nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 2560x1440@59.95hz, 1920x1080@144.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2070/PCIe/SSE2
           version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 430.26
```

Screenshot of nvidia settings:

[image: nvidia settings]

Comment: Is that an optimus or nvidia only laptop? if you install `inxi` and run this it'll show if you don't know. `inxi -G`

Comment: @doug I updated the question with the output you asked for.

Comment: the checkbox is fully available and checkable in my Ubuntu 18.04-3's nvidia-440 settings Just FYI, but still working terribly with gnome

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update 08/09/2019:**

It seems that [gord0](https://askubuntu.com/users/626431/gord0) (OP) is right in their [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170247/screen-tearing-solution-doesnt-work-for-me/1170313?noredirect=1#comment1954671_1170313). You don't need to go through all of the steps that I had previously described (I'm not deleting them, just in case that someone finds them helpful) to get rid of tearing.

What you have to do to is:

1. Open NVIDIA X Server Settings.
2. Go to *X Server Display Configuration*.
3. Select the screen that you want.
4. Click the *Advanced* button.
5. Enable *Force Composition Pipeline* or *Force Full Composition Pipeline* (try both and enable the one that gives you the best results).
6. Click the *Apply* button.

Alternatively, you can enable *Force Composition Pipeline* or *Force Full Composition Pipeline* by running the following commands in your terminal:

- For *Force Composition Pipeline*:

  ```
  nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="$(xrandr | sed -nr '/(\S+) connected (primary )?([0-9]+x[0-9]+)(\+\S+).*/{ s//\1: \3 \4 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }, /; H}; ${ g; s/\n//g; s/, $//; p }')"
  ```
- For *Force Full Composition Pipeline*:

  ```
  nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="$(xrandr | sed -nr '/(\S+) connected (primary )?([0-9]+x[0-9]+)(\+\S+).*/{ s//\1: \3 \4 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }, /; H}; ${ g; s/\n//g; s/, $//; p }')"
  ```

These commands use `xrandr` and `sed` with some [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) to get the current monitor setup in the appropriate format and use it as input to the `nvidia=settings --assign` command, which enables the desired setting.

You should now have no screen tearing.

In case the changes are not persistent and get discarded after reboot, you can  do the following:

1. Run the appropriate, for your case, command from the commands above and make sure that it works correctly, that is you have no screen tearing in your monitors.
2. Add one of the following commands (depending on what worked best for you) to your Startup Applications.

   - For *Force Composition Pipeline*:

     ```
     bash -c "sleep 10 && nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode=\"$(xrandr | sed -nr '/(\S+) connected (primary )?([0-9]+x[0-9]+)(\+\S+).*/{ s//\1: \3 \4 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }, /; H}; ${ g; s/\n//g; s/, $//; p }')\""
     ```
   - For *Force Full Composition Pipeline*:

     ```
     bash -c "sleep 10 && nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode=\"$(xrandr | sed -nr '/(\S+) connected (primary )?([0-9]+x[0-9]+)(\+\S+).*/{ s//\1: \3 \4 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }, /; H}; ${ g; s/\n//g; s/, $//; p }')\""
     ```

   The `sleep 10` command just adds a 10 seconds delay to ensure that the desktop has fully loaded before running the `nvidia=settings --assign ...` command. You may need to add a larger delay if your desktop takes more time to fully load.

Alternatively, you can save the configuration by clicking *Save to X Configuration File* button in NVIDIA X Server Settings.

---

**Old answer. Try these if the above method doesn't work for you.**

What is suggested in the answer you posted is correct for Ubuntu 16.04.

For Ubuntu 18.04 and later versions, you have to change `options nvidia_387_drm modeset=1` to `options nvidia-drm modeset=1` (the Nvidia driver version is no longer needed).

So what you have to do is:

1. Create a file in your `/etc/modprobe.d` directory called `zz-nvidia-modeset.conf`

   ```
   nano /etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia-modeset.conf
   ```
2. Add the following lines to it:

   ```
   #enable prime-sync
   options nvidia-drm modeset=1
   ```
3. Save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
4. From the terminal run:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
5. Reboot.

To enable the NVIDIA adapter, after rebooting you have to run:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Then log out and log back in.

**Edit:** If you are using GNOME, you may have to use another display manager, such as `lightdm`, since `gdm` does not allow external monitors to work with `nomodeset=1` (I had to do this on 18.04 but not on 20.04).

- To install `lightdm` run:

  ```
  sudo apt install lightdm
  ```
- After installing `lightdm` run

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  and select it as your display manager in the terminal window that appears.

Comment: Nope. You this is incorrect. You're listing the steps I already did. I did them again and sure enough bye bye external monitor. Did `sudo prime-select nvidia` it told me I was already using nvidia. Undid the solution, well hello external monitor. Hello tearing.

Comment: The instructions are correct. The problem is `gdm`, if you are using Gnome. You have to use `lightdm` as your display manager, since `gdm` with `nomodeset` does not allow external monitors. The steps above are what I do to have my second monitor without tearing on Xubuntu. I have read them in an Ask Ubuntu post that I couldn't find yesterday, but I found it today. Here it is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079135/screen-tearing-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @gord0 I updated my answer to include the steps to install `lightdm`.

Comment: The monitor stays connected, tearing still happens.

Comment: Did you play around with the Nvidia settings? For example, did you enable *Force Full Composition Pipeline* for your external monitor?

Comment: updated question with screen shot

Comment: So did you enable *Force Full Composition Pipeline*? Did it have any effect?

Comment: It would seem enabling it fixes tearing. I suspect I didn't need to do any of the other steps other than checking that box.

Comment: @gord0 I updated my answer based on your last comment. Please check it out and tell me what you think. May I also suggest that you change the title of the question, so that others with the same problem can find it more easily?

Comment: Edited the title.

Comment: It did fix my screen tearing issue on 20.04 lts, but since i changed the display manager to lightdm, ubuntu's screen lock is no longer working

Comment: @z3r0c00l_2k In 20.04 I didn't have to switch to LightDM to remove screen tearing. GDM works fine, at least in my case. So, maybe try to change your display manager to GDM by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and selecting GDM.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Ubuntu 20.04 but this other answer worked perfectly: https://askubuntu.com/a/1266161/21195

Comment: FYI, this does not work on some Optimus configurations as they don't have that force composition option