# Ubuntu 20.04 - Screen Tearing

Tags: nvidia, screen, tearing

Since I installed Ubuntu 20.04 I notice that there is Screen tearing when playing videos, it happens in several browsers and it is noticeable when moving the windows within the screen, when scrolling it is also noticeable. How is this problem solved?

Comment: Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with a GTX 960M on my Lenovo ideaPad Y700 and the following worked for me.

Open a terminal and run

`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-drm-nomodeset.conf`

In the file, write the following line:

`options nvidia-drm modeset=1`

Save the file. Back into the terminal, update `initramfs` by running:

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

Reboot.

Source: [ubuntuhandbook.org](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/fix-screen-tearing-ubuntu-18-04-optimus-laptops/)

---

If the previous step didn't work, there is another solution that you can try:

`$ xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --set "PRIME Synchronization" 1`

Reboot.

This command will enable the sync in your hybrid card.

To check that sync has been enable:
`$ sudo cat /sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset`

it should return `Y` now.

Reboot.

Comment: I have a GT 635M Nvidia card and that steps don't work!

Comment: What drivers are you using?

Comment: I used the private drivers it doesn't work and the free drivers too

Comment: I amended the solution to include an alternative. Hope it works!

Comment: Why is there a need to update "intramfs"?

Comment: Not working on Ubuntu 21.04 with nvidia 460 drivers for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfL_JkcEFbE) video to see if you still have screen tearing.
2. Try the solution provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170247/how-do-i-solve-screen-tearing-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-nvidia/1170313#1170313).
3. What helped in my specific case was that I switched the driver used for my NVIDIA GP107M when using the "Additional Drivers" application and switched from nvidia-driver-440 to nvidia-driver-435.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1252499/1110069) to work because the DRM kernel mode setting would not get updated.

Then I stumbled upon [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1266161/1110069) explaining how to set that kernel boot parameter through GRUB instead.
This worked for me on my laptop running Ubuntu 21.04 with the 470 drivers and a GTX 1050M GPU.

Steps based on [this Ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) that describes how to set boot params through GRUB:

1. Open the file `/etc/default/grub` for editing (e.g. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`). It should already exist.
2. Change the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, adding the parameter `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to the text inside the double-quotes. If you haven't added any parameters before, it likely just contains `quiet splash`.
   So the changed line would be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1"`.
3. Now save the file and run `sudo update-grub` to make the changes take effect.
4. Restart the system.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't have the "Enable Force Composition Pipeline or Force Full Composition Pipeline" setting in the graphical Nvidia X server setting window nor did the command `$ xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --set "PRIME Synchronization" 1` worked for me (it just didn't change the parameter value for some reason).

But when under "RRIME profiles" of the "NVIDIA X Server Settings" I selected "NVIDIA On-Demand" and restarted I got rid of the screen tearing.

Note: somebody commented that's because on demand uses intel not nvidia so it's probably not a very good solution

Comment: That's because the On-demand uses Intel unless explicitly commanded to use nvidia.