# Screen Tearing Nvidia/Intel ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, intel

i installed ubuntu 20.04 a few times. in the first installs i have been able to see my Intel listed in the additional drivers( with 4 nvidia and 1 nouveau driver shown above it). but for my last 3 installs it (Intel) does not appear.

when i scroll or play a video the screen is tearing up, and that is really annoying, also i fear i can damage the hardware.

can this be because of the drivers are not installed properly?

also can i switch between the two processors to use Intel for lightweight use like browsing, and Nvidia for Blender, games and anything else that requires GPU?

asus fx502vmz + ssd for Ubuntu (no other OSs are installed)

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz

NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] nvidia 440 driver is in use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 - Screen Tearing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230531/ubuntu-20-04-screen-tearing)

Comment: unfortunately not. 
"(gedit:36097): Tepl-WARNING **: 22:54:20.627: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata."

Comment: Use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1310431/1000624)

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry as screen tearing will not damage your hardware, it is simply that the rate of displaying of the video's picture on the screen is different from your screen's refresh rate.

Screen tearing is a driver issue, so will have to be fixed at the driver level. If you have the NVidia proprietary driver installed, open the Nvidia X Server Settings dialog and select 'X Server Display Configuration' option, then select either 'Force Composition Pipeline' or 'Force Full Composition Pipeline' and click on Apply.
https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/how-to-an-update-on-fixing-screen-tearing-on-linux-with-an-nvidia-gpu.8892/page=4

It is possible run on on the Intel GPU and launch various apps using the Nvidia GPU. See the link below on how to do this, though the simpler option is to just go exclusively off your Nvidia GPU.
http://www.hadess.net/2020/05/dual-gpu-support-launch-on-discrete-gpu.html