# Screen Tearing - Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia/Intel graphics(Nvidia Optimus)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, nvidia-optimus

When I use X.ORG X server-Nouveau display driver, I don't have any problem.

But whenever I install any version of `NVIDIA driver` (460/450), I encounter with Screen Tearing.

[image]

I tried many solutions but non of them work.

---

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Graphic Card: NVIDIA 960M
- Integrated Graphic: Intel HD 530

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all install **Nvidia driver**.

**Solved by:**

1. Open the `/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` file and add
   the following line:

   ```
   options nvidia-drm modeset=1
   ```

[image: nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf file content]

2. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

---

**Installing Nvidia driver commands:**

- List available drivers:  `ubuntu-drivers devices`
- Install the best driver: `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
- Check for successful installation after a reboot: `nvidia-smi`

[image: nvidia-smi]