# Focal fossa 20.04 nvidia problems

Tags: drivers, nvidia, screen

I have switched to Ubuntu recently and I just can't get nvidia to work properly, major problem is screen tearing, however there are many more.

GTX 1660TI
I have tried to solve screen tearing with multiple ways, using the control panel and forcing the compositor pipeline and both answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230531/ubuntu-20-04-screen-tearing) (which just made it worse by making the screen tearing even harder), while enabling the composition pipeline / syncing to Vblank does fix the screen tearing, the Framerate drops
noticeably.

I know there are probably duplicates of this, but they are all a little outdated and none of the answers seem to work for me

I have tried using these drivers : nvidia-460, nvidia-470, nvidia-450, nvidia-418, and nouveau

Hopefully someone can help me, because Ubuntu is quite unusable like this

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases come with two kernel stack choices; which have you tried?

Comment: `hostnamectl | grep Kernel` spits out Linux 5.11.0-34-generic
I don't recall specifically choosing a version though, I haven't tried switching

Comment: 5.11 means you're using the HWE (hardware enablement) kernel stack; for Server installs the default is GA but there is an option to change it at install time, for Desktop ISOs it's selected by the ISO used (all Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 ISOs use HWE, but 20.04 *flavor* ISOs default is chosen by ISO used as per prior releases).  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for more detail; and how to add GA kernel stack (you can have both installed; selected at grub/boot-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing kernels from 5.11 HWE to GA 5.4 had done the trick, this isn't ideal as there are still some problems with nvidia, but this is the closest I got and ubuntu is usable like this